# windows10内のUbuntuでpython環境をもう一度構築する必要がありますか?

Tags: python, ubuntu, windows-10

いままでwindows10でpythonを動かしていました　しかしdeepspeedを使うためにはUbuntu環境でやる必要があるらしく　Ubuntuを入れました

当然さらの状態で　pythonコマンド動きません　また一から構築する必要がありますか？
今の環境をそのままコピーして使うことはできませんか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windowsの実行可能ファイルは当然Ubuntuでは動きません。UbuntuにはUbuntuで実行可能なPythonをインストールしましょう。UbuntuにはPython3が最初から入っているのではないかと思いますが、もし無かったらインストールしましょう。やり方がわからなければ ubuntu python インストール apt といったキーワードで検索してください。

Comment: ほんとですね　pythonではなくpython3なんですね　windowsだとpythonで起動するのでいつものようにやって動かなかったで入っていないと思ってしまいました